# Using WordPress REST API in C# to get post author display name

Tags: c#

I am writing a C# application and using the WordPressPCL nuget package. I have the code in place to get the author of a post, but right now it is returning the author ID instead of a name. I would like to return the author's name instead of the ID. Here is the code I have right now.

```
var client = new WordPressClient(site);

var post = client.Posts.GetByID(postID).Result;

var author = post.Author.ToString();
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with their nuget package, is Author an object or a property? If it is an object you will have to access the right property on the object like `post.Author.Name` if it is a property you might need to make another call using that value to get the Author object.

Comment: Author is a property in this case.

Comment: Then you have to call something like client.Authors.GetById(author).Result;

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the author details from the users API. Also when you call the client, you should await instead of calling .Result (as this is blocking code)

```
var client = new WordPressClient(site);

var post = await client.Posts.GetByID(postID);

var author = await client.Users.GetByID(post.Author);
```